# C Program find largest element and its index value in the array

Tags: arrays, c

Below code is to find the largest value in the array list along with its index value but the problem is that m not getting any output.

Taking input from user.

Can anyone help me too know where i am making mistakes

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i, max_index, size, max;

printf("\n Enter the size of the array: ");
scanf("%d", &size);
int arr[size];

printf("Please enter numbers:\n ");

for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}
max  = arr[0];//start off assuming that the 1st element is the max
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)//now compare it with the rest of the array, updataing the max all 
along
{
if (arr[i] > max) {
    max = arr[i];
    max_index = i;
    }
}
printf("Largest element = %d at index %d", max, max_index);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: -2

Its similar to check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584197/c-program-to-output-the-largest-element-of-array-with-the-index-of-the-largest-e/52611136#:~:text=int%20imax%20%3D%200%3B%20for%20(,arr%5Bimax%5D%2C%20imax)%3B

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger. If your program doesn't work the next step is to debug it. Surely you can find out more than just "not getting any output". What is the program doing and where does it not run as you expect? All things you can find out with a debugger. FWIW, your program [looks ok](https://ideone.com/Z9Z1Vc) to me. Maybe you are entering the input correctly or not running it correctly.

Comment: Just a quick comment... The size of array should of type size_t.